SQL transactions work, but expected to be deadlocked
I have two tables Books and Journals
and I have two transactions:
BEGIN TRAN 
UPDATE Journals SET Pages = 20 

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:07'

SELECT * FROM Books

Commit;

And
 BEGIN TRAN  
 UPDATE Books SET Pages = 30 

 WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:07'

 SELECT * FROM Journals

Commit;

Then I run these two in two separate windows and they complete just fine!
I expect them to be deadlocked. My thoughts are the following:

Transaction A locks Journals while Transaction B locks Books
Transaction A can't read from table Books, since Books is locked for Update
Transaction B can't read from table Journals, since Journals is locked as well

Where am I wrong in my thoughts??

I do get a deadlock, so I feel like there's something else going on. Perhaps the isolation level of your connection? Is, perhaps, your database set to READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT? If I use a database with that isolation level, I don't get a deadlock  (as expected), as the statement that runs first returns the prior value for Pages.

Do you want a deadlock? or is this curiosity?

Azure SQL defaults to READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT by the way.

@P.Salmon This is not just a curiosity. This is desire not to catch this issue on Production

Presumably your database has READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT enabled, then the behaviour is expected. If your database has this enabled then whichever is the first statement to run the SELECT will return the unUPDATEd values for the other table. So, if both tables had the value 10 in every row for the column Pages, then the statement that ran first would return 10 and the other statement would return either 20 or 30.
If, however, your database does not have READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT enabled, then you will get a deadlock, with an error like so:

Msg 1205, Level 13, State 45, Line 9
Transaction (Process ID 58) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

And a deadlock graph like so:

So the real question is, do you want a deadlock? If so, then is READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT the right choice for you? Only you can answer that.

But then you get write skew, which is even more pernicious IMO

Yeah, I agree that catering for write skew with the snapshot isolated is important, @Charlieface , and why I denote only th OP can really answer if they should be using it or not; we don't know what the database is actually being used for.
